# How to setup dns to resolve selective ip locally and others to forward

Tags: 14.04, dns, webserver, bind

I have setup bind server using the [following link](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/configure-dns-server-ubuntu-14-04/)

And added few extra lines in `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` as

```
Recursion yes;
allow-query { 0.0.0.0/0; };
```

and an extra lamp server with web server for example.com hosted on bind server machine with ip 192.168.2.2.

Now I configured two separate machines with ip 192.168.2.3 and 2.4 with dns 2.2 for each.

Now I want that machine 192.168.2.3 should be able to open locally hosted example.com and all other queries pertaining to other websites should be resolved by 8.8.8.8

And machine with 192.168.2.4 should not be able to resolve locally hosted example.com but its dns queries should directly be resolved by 8.8.8.8 open dns.

Both machines dns will remain 192.168.2.2 but above scenario should also be fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if bind overrides these, but you could try to direct queries to example.com to your httpd server, by settings the IP address of your lamp host in /etc/hosts of the machine 192.168.2.3, e.g.:

```
192.168.2.2    example.com
```

As for "machine with 192.168.2.4 should not be able to resolve locally hosted example.com", you could try adding this to /etc/hosts in 192.168.2.4 in order to block the access to example.com:

```
127.0.0.1    example.com
```

or some other IP address instead of 127.0.0.1, which isn't actually used by your httpd server.

Comment: but what about I want 2.4 to access example.com resolved from 8.8.8.8 and even I will not be having access to 2.3 machine  to do changes in its /etc/host file. What I have is access to just my dns server with apache server hosted on it.